# how to count and sum of the values of a column in a tibble in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

For example, I have this tibble:

```
       nationality    Other
[1,]          White     1 ------> I want to add
[2,]          Mexican   0
[3,]          American  0
[4,]          Asian     1 -------> I want to add
[5,]          af        1 -------> I want to add
[6,]          American  0
```

I want to somehow sum up the values in Other and create it's own tibble:

```
       Other
[1,]     3
```

I tried using sum(), but it gives me

```
  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

In addition to that, tally() gives me this, it counts the number of rows in the column:

```
      n
1     88
```

Here is the code:

```
natgroups3 <- ibtclean %>% select(nationality) %>%mutate(Other = ifelse(str_detect(nationality, "af|White|Asian|white|Middle-Eastern"), yes = 1, no = 0)) %>% drop_na()
```

Comment: Try `ibtclean  %>% filter(nationality %in% c('White', 'af', 'Asian', 'white', 'Middle-Eastern')) %>% summarise(Other = sum(Other))` or `ibtclean %>% filter(as.logical(Other)) %>% summarise(Other = sum(Other))`

Comment: what about sum(as.numeric(x))?

Comment: Thanks! The first one worked very nicely, unfortunately, sum(as.numeric()) gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the *tidyverse* library. I prepared a sample code that recreates a tibble **d** with your structure and calculates the target tibble **c** with the count of rows with the column *other* equals to 1.

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- tribble(~nationality, ~other, 'White', 0, 'Mexican', 1, 'Amrican', 0, 'Asian', 1, 'af', 1)
d
c <- d %>% count(other) %>% filter(other == 1) %>% select('Other' = n)
c
```

You can also select the column *other* and calculate its sum with the following code (according to your business need)

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- tribble(~nationality, ~other, 'White', 0, 'Mexican', 1, 'Amrican', 0, 'Asian', 1, 'af', 1)
d
c <- d %>% select(other) %>% summarise('Other'=sum(other))
c
```

Both of the code snippets produce the following result

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  nationality other
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 White           0
2 Mexican         1
3 Amrican         0
4 Asian           1
5 af              1
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  Other
  <dbl>
1     3
```

I hope these snippets solve your issue